# What's wrong with my Rails 3 Many-to-Many Associaton?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I can't figure out what I"m doing wrong here.. I can't seem to get the Event class correct in regards to the "has_many  :creators" line...   I created an rspec test to verify that an event instantiation will respond to 'creators' but I can't get it to pass...  Any thoughts appreciated!

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many    :event_invitations
has_many    :creators,   :through => :event_invitations,
                 :source => :creator,
                 :class_name => "User"

class EventInvitation < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to  :user
belongs_to  :event

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many  :event_invitations,   :foreign_key => :creator_id
  has_many  :created_events,      :through => :event_invitations,
                                  :source => :event
```

Comment: The `Event` *class* should not respond to `creators`. `creators` is an instance method and only an `Event` *instance* will respond to it, e.g. `Event.first.creators`.

Comment: Sorry you are absolutely right.. I can't get any event objects to respond to 'creators' (i.e. \@fun = Event.new ... @fun.creators is throwing the exeption)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EventInvitation belongs_to 'user', but you're storing 'creator_id'. You need to either store 'user_id', or call the association 'creator'.

```
belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'
```

And in your Event model, you can use this:

```
has_many :creators, :through => :event_invitations
```

Comment: Thank you!! You nailed it and taught me something about Rails & ActiveRecord in the process.  Knowing is half the battle.